# Join two tables using LISTAGG or other concatenation functions

Tags: sql, oracle, concatenation, join, listagg

I have the following two tables:

```
Subject
-----------------------------------------------
   ID    | SUBJECT_ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME 
-----------------------------------------------
2456969  |  0002531   |    Sam     |   White
1371093  |  0002301   |    Tom     |   Andrew
2456840  |  0002529   |    Chris   |   Williams


Subject Countries
--------------------------------
   ID    | ID_OWNER | COUNTRIES  
--------------------------------
2445162  |  2444907 |   303
2457722  |  2457721 |   302
2457650  |  2457649 |   211
```

I need to use LISTAGG function or some other concatenation function to join the two table together to output the values for "Countries" in a single row.

My current query looks like the following:

```
sql.append("SELECT s.id, ");
sql.append("     s.subject_id AS subjectId, "); 
sql.append("     s.first_name AS firstName, "); 
sql.append("     s.last_name AS lastName, ");
sql.append("     listagg(sc.countries, ', ') within group (order by sc.countries) AS countriesOfCit ");
sql.append("FROM t_subject s ");
sql.append("     JOIN m_subject_countries sc ");
sql.append("     ON s.id = sc.id_owner ");
sql.append("     group by s.id ");
```

and I've been getting "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression" error

Comment: This is a very strange data model you may want to fix. If there is a table called `t_subject` we can surmise it's containing subjects. You are using IDs in order to uniqely identify a subject record. One would call this ID `id` or `subject_id` or `id_subject`. You, however, have one `id` column and one `subject_id` column in the table. That doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: Then there is a table called `m_subject_countries` that obviously combines countries with subjects. We'd expect a `subject_id` in the table, but there only is an `owner_id` that you treat like a subject ID. Why is it called `owner_id` then? This makes us expect a table called `t_owner` or the like. Then there is a column `countries` and we'd expect a cell to contain a string of countries. But no, it contains a single value, so that should be `country` (singular). Looking at the content however, there is no country, but some number. Is this a `country_id` maybe, referencing some country record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All columns (not contained in `LISTAGG`) should be in the `GROUP BY` clause: `s.id, s.subject_id, s.first_name, s.last_name`

Answer (score 0):

You group by `t_subject.id` and expect to be able to select all functionally dependent columns, such as `t_subject.first_name` and `t_subject.last_name`. This is valid according to the SQL standard.

Oracle, however, doesn't comply with the standard here and requires you to explicitely name all columns in your `GROUP BY` clause that you want to select unaggregated.

```
group by s.id, s.subject_id, s.first_name, s.last_name
```

should solve this issue.

Another solution is to aggregate before joining:

```
SELECT 
  s.id, 
  s.subject_id AS subjectId,  
  s.first_name AS firstName,  
  s.last_name AS lastName, 
  sc.countriesOfCit 
FROM t_subject s
JOIN 
(
  select
    id_owner,
    listagg(countries, ', ') within group (order by countries) AS countriesOfCit 
  from m_subject_countries
  group by id_owner
) sc ON sc.id_owner = s.id;
```